# Why does controls="controls" get cut off here?

Tags: javascript, php, html, tinymce

We are adding videos in our project by using tinyMCE file manager. Videos are uploaded and added with the code. But the problem is, after adding a video, we insert it into database and then it loses some html data.

For example, the line

```
<video width="300" height="150" controls="controls">
    <source src="/allonkid/upload/pages/Kill Dil - Title Song (HQ Video) [FreshMaza.Info].mp4" type="video/mp4" /><br />
</video>
```

converts to the following line after a submit:

```
<video width="300" height="150" c>
    <source src="/allonkid/upload/pages/Kill Dil - Title Song (HQ Video) [FreshMaza.Info].mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

**=> The `controls="controls"` is changed into `c`. Why does this happen?**

PS: If I remove tinyMCE editor and put this into a simple `textarea` then I get the same result.

---

[Edit]
This is my text area definition:

```
<textarea name="pagebody" id="pagebody2" cols="30" rows="20" >
    <?php echo $pageArray['body']; ?>
</textarea>
```

and my function

```
function updatepage() { pr($_POST); die; }
```

Comment: Please post the function where you insert/update your database with the content of the textarea.

Comment: thanks for your suggession but i dont understand. please explain it.

Comment: Somewhere in your sourcecode you update the database with the new content in the textarea. My guess is that there's somekind of html-purifier that removes unknown tags and properties, I guess it does not know about the controls-property, so it deletes it.

Comment: i dont use any html-purifier. before insert, i just  print textarea data then i found its changed.

Comment: I understand but your code is changing it somewhere, we need to see the code (all of the code before the insert) to help.

Comment: Hi, your textarea look like this example http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php?

Comment: yup @Nacho its like this.

Comment: @JeroendeJong : <textarea  name="pagebody" id="pagebody2" cols="30" rows="20" ><?php echo $pageArray['body']; ?></textarea>  This is my html..

And

function updatepage()
 {
  pr($_POST); die;
}
this is some php code..

Comment: No the php code where $pageArray['body'] is filled with the content of $_GET['pagebody']/$_POST['pagebody'].

Comment: its remove before i insert into database.

Comment: After submit from, i dont use anything. i just use print_r function to view posted data.

Comment: The example works fine... look your code, something remove this.... you can post all the code?

Comment: Whats happens if you put this in different order, like this "<video controls="controls" width="300" height="150">"?

Comment: nothing change when i put it in different order. And yes i know there is mistake in my code. but i use this only with textarea nothing on the page and just check after submit form. it changed the controls tag

Comment: What is the code if you right-click on the element and inspect it? Is this a function of the browser reducing the code for its own syntax? e.g. `controls="controls"` might be converted to just `controls` if that's what the browser likes.

Comment: Please give me a better solution.